# Is there an antenna problem with CAN Bus selectable split termination header pin?

Tags: differential, emc, can, emi-filtering, termination

I am trying to implement a jumper-selectable CAN Bus termination with a SPLIT configuration, as shown in this Analog Devices example:
[image: Analog Devices Split Termination with Jumper-selectable header pins]

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC2063AF.PDF

It occurred to me that there might be a big antenna when the jumper is removed. The 0.3" header pins on JP2 might radiate at 1Mhz since they are connected to CANH and CANL.

Is this a potential noise problem? If so, would a good way to eliminate the problem be to move the capacitor on SPLIT to the other side of the jumper, so it can attenuate the antenna signal?

Before:
[image: CAN Split Termination with Selectable Jumper]

After:
[image: CAN Split Termination with Selectable Jumper, capacitors stopping antenna]

**Edit 1** Here is my full "before" schematic to show the rest of the circuit.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that small stub is much of a concern (and there's the resistors on it too). But I guess for an ideal layout, place the resistor pads directly on the CAN traces, so that the whole stub has relatively much higher resistance than the signal trace. Alternatively you could place the jumper on the CAN trace, before the resistor.

Comment: Btw consider placing a common mode choke on CANH + CANL. And why are C1 and C3 very similar values? Any why are you using a polarized 6u8F cap for? Use a ceramic, you only need something rated for 10V or so.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for putting it into perspective. I wasn't sure if there was much to be concerned about. So it sounds like the more of the stub is after the resistance, the less antenna radiation there will be?

Comment: @Lundin that is good advice, I do have a common mode choke just out of view on those screenshots. The C1 and C3 6.8uF and 2.2uF caps are from Analog Device's reference design, only the "before" and "after" screenshots are mine. My CAN PHY has 0.1uF and 10uF ceramic decoupling/bypass caps.

Comment: The main concerns regarding stubs isn't radiated emissions but signal bounce and maybe impedance mismatching. Classic CAN can handle stubs up to 0.3m somewhere. Split termination seems to mainly be thing for CAN FD however, meaning > 1MHz baudrate. The higher the speed, the pickier the layout will be regarding stubs and ideal impedance. Regarding the updated schematic, maybe consider if the TVS should be before or after the terminating resistors. I'm not sure if it matters, check the datasheet regarding internal protection of the split pin.

Comment: @Lundin good point, in my schematic I have the terminating resistor first, but the TVS is actually first in my layout.

Comment: You've made a layout which isn't coupled with the schematic? That's probably _the_ ultimate sin in electronics design. Uninstall your CAD tool right now, get a real one. It should _force_ you to pair the schematic with the PCB layout or otherwise it is trash.

Comment: @Lundin you are right that schematics should always be coupled with layouts. But the order of parallel branches in the schematic is not enforced on the layout by any PCB software I've used.